# Run Cypress tests in headless Chrome

Tags: cypress

Trying to launch cypress tests with

```
--headless --browser chrome
```

how it's described in the official documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run)

But for some reason --headless parameter is not recognizable and I'm getting

```
error: unknown option: --headless
```

Can't get what's wrong, looks like everything is pretty straightforward but can't get it working.

My application parameters:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --headless --browser chrome --env cfg=dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this once,

./node_modules/.bin/cypress run -- --headless --browser chrome --env cfg=dev